# Invalid character returned in IE but not in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: ajax, reactjs, internet-explorer, asp.net-core

I'm using fetch to return a JSON payload to a React SPA. My web server backend is ASP.NET Core 2.0. I recently updated to ASP.NET Core 2.0 and for the life of me can't figure out why IE no longer works with the web application.

The fetch is pretty straight forward.

```
fetch(getApiPath() + url, {
    credentials: 'include'
})
.then(function(response){
    if (response.status === 401 && history) {
        history.push("/login")
        throw new Error('Redirecting to login');
    } else if (response.status === 200) {
        return response.json();
    } else {
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
})
.then(success)
.catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e)
});
```

The server end is also pretty straight forward.

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("/dashboard")]
    public object Index()
    {
        Log.Debug("Index");
        return new { dashboard = _dashboard, authenticated = HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated };
    }
```

The problem manifests itself in a "Invalid Character" error in IE. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox. When looking at the response body, the IE response, is in fact an invalid character while in Chrome, it is the JSON payload.

[image]

I'm a little unsure where to even start looking into why IE wouldn't receive or parse the HTTP response correctly. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Making a cross-origin request from a Webpack Dev Server running on port 10000 to a local ASP.NET Core app running on 10001. When packaged for deployment, both the React App and the ASP.NET Core App run on 10000.

Headers between the two requests.

IE Request

[image]

IE Response

[image]

Chrome

[image]

Updated the endpoint to return an IActionResult and explicitly returning JSON. Same result. I've also realized it doesn't work in Edge either.

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("/dashboard")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Json(
            new { dashboard = _dashboard, authenticated = HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing a polyfill?

Comment: More info is needed here. Are you making a cross-origin request? Have you compared the request headers from IE and Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Without additional info I suspect the issue is related to ASP.Net's [content negotiation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation) and the fact your method return type is `object`. Don't use `object`, this is not Java :))

Before anything else, make sure fetch is sending an `Accept: application/json` header in IE.

I would also recommend for you to change the return type to `IActionResult` (or `JSONResult` if you want to force JSON) for your controller methods.

Comment: Thanks. Gave it a shot but it still seems to fail in IE but not in Chrome\Firefox. I updated my question with headers.